# JSON to PHP sending/ receiving variables with image data

Tags: php, jquery, html, json, ajax

UPDATE: SOLVED! (Answer below)
I am trying to add vars with an image file I am uploading. I am able to upload the image fine but I can't seem to send the wanted vars to php and send them back etc.

I am hoping to send at least this var called $Destination to php, along with image data, which is working, and maybe other vars too. Below is the line I am trying to send.

```
var Dest = '<? echo $Destination;?>';
```

Here is my script:

```
 function myFunction() {
    var = Dest: '<? echo $Destination;?>'; // This one
    var file_data = $('#ImageuploadBtn').prop('files')[0];   
    var form_data = new FormData();                  
    form_data.append('file', file_data);

    $.ajax({
                url: 'admin/myUpload.php',
                dataType: 'text',  
                cache: false,
                contentType: false,
                processData: false,
                data: form_data,                         
                type: 'POST',
                success: function(php_script_response)
                { 
                    console.log(php_script_response);
                    var html = '<img src="../files/' + php_script_response + '" class="DisplayMainImage img-responsive">';

                    $( ".MainImage" ).replaceWith(html);
                }
     });
```

My PHP:

```
<?php
    if ( 0 < $_FILES['file']['error'] ) {
        echo 'Error: ' . $_FILES['file']['error'] . '<br>';
    }
    else {
        move_uploaded_file($_FILES['file']['tmp_name'], '../files/' . $_FILES['file']['name']);
        $Message = $_FILES['file']['name'];
        //// $Destination DOES NOT WORK
        $Destination = $_POST['Dest']; /// NO WORK
        echo $Message;

    }
?>
```

SOLVED ISSUE: I needed these lines.

```
var Dest = '<? echo $Destination;?>';
    form_data.append('Dest', Dest);
```

Comment: It's a little confusing, you're not sending anything other than the image, did you at least try to `form_data.append('Dest', Dest);` to add the data?

Comment: That did it. Oh man. Thank you.

Comment: Actually, @adeneo should have been the one to have posted an answer, given the timestamps here. I think it's only fair.

Comment: Yes, @adeneo, please pose your answer and I will give you credit. That's what did it for me.

Comment: Marc B seems to have the right idea, just accept that one

Answer (score 3):

This is a syntax error:

```
var = Dest: '<? echo $Destination;?>'; // This one
          ^---
```

and that will kill the entire `<script>` block, keeping your ajax call from ever occuring.

And even if that variable assignment worked, you don't ever USE it in your ajax code. You have a `formdata`, but the only thing you put in there is that one file item.

Answer (score 1):

First off all

```
var = Dest: '<? echo $Destination;?>';
```

will render to something like this:

```
var = Dest: 'some text from $Destination php var';
```

which is not correct js syntax. Since it's syntax error, script execution will stop on this moment. Maybe you meant something like this:

```
var dest = '<? echo $Destination;?>';
```

You can open developer tools in browser and see on js console rendered source. It will show you script errors. For example in chrome, you press `ctrl + shift + i` and go to console tab.

Answer (score 0):

This was needed.

```
var Dest = '<? echo $Destination;?>';
form_data.append('Dest', Dest);
```